# When im submitting the button its showing popup message but also saving in the data base

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webforms, ado.net

// This is my js file
function validate() {

```
var z = document.forms["form1"]["sponsorid"].value;
if (!z.match(/^\d+/)) {
    alert("Sponsor id should be in Numbers only")
    return false
}
var z2 = document.forms["form1"]["clientname"].value;
if (!z2.match(/^[a-zA-Z_ ]+$/)) {
    alert("Client Name should be in Alphabets only")
    return false
}
var z3 = document.forms["form1"]["additionalnumber"].value;
if (!z3.match(/^\d+/)) {
    alert("Additional Number should be in Numbers only")
    return false
}
var z4 = document.forms["form1"]["district"].value;
if (!z4.match(/^[a-zA-Z_ ]+$/)) {
    alert("District should be in Alphabets only")
    return false
}
var z5 = document.forms["form1"]["mainownerid"].value;
if (!z5.match(/^\d+/)) {
    alert("Main Owner ID should be in Numbers only")
    btnsave.Click(false)
}
var z6 = document.forms["form1"]["sponsorname"].value;
if (!z6.match(/^[a-zA-Z_ ]+$/)) {
    alert("Sponsor Name should be in Alphabets only")
    return false
}
var z7 = document.forms["form1"]["mobileno"].value;
if (!z7.match(/^\d+/)) {
    alert("Mobile Number should be in Numbers only")
    return false
}
var z8 = document.forms["form1"]["emailid"].value;
if (!z8.match(/\S+@\S+\.\S+/)) {
    alert("Enter correct Email Id")
    return false
}
var z9 = document.forms["form1"]["phoneno"].value;
if (!z9.match(/^\d+/)) {
    alert("Phone Number should be in Numbers only")
    return false
}
return true
```

}

//This is my vb file
Protected Sub btnsave_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click

```
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constring)
```

....content...
End Sub

//This is in my aspx file
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnsave" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/save.gif" TabIndex="02" OnClientClick="validate()" />

Comment: And what is the problem, specifically?? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Add your own efforts such as coding approaches and docs research.

Comment: So you're getting the alert (from validation) but it's also processing your ImageButtonClick from the code-behind, which it shouldn't be doing. You might try to have your ````OnClientClick = "return validate()"```` or even go as far as passing in the ````event```` object and using ````event.preventDefault()```` from stopping the button click from registering.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand your problem consist in submitting in a wrong case of validation. Means you wont want to submit if validation returns false. If so, you have to specify the default button of submit action on your form. A piece of code for “how to”:

pay attention on `defaultbutton="Button1"`

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button1"  
  <%--other code here--%>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="False" />
</form>
```